# Как заменить Xamarin версию на нативную

Tags: android, xamarin

У меня есть приложение написанное на xamarin`e и есть нативная версия этого приложения, написанная на java/kotlin.

Как сделать так, чтобы при установке они были взаимозаменяемыми?

package name стоит одинаковый, но при установке на эмулятор по прежнему сохраняются 2 приложения

Comment: В `gradle.build` апп-модуля проверьте `applicationId` - он переопределяет package name при сборке

Comment: @woesss так и есть, почему-то автоматически не поменялся